# how to stream android device to PC

Tags: android, smartphone

I need to stream the videos from an android device(not an android phone, but a kind of smartphone-like glasses) to a PC. I have researched that there are several APPs that can do the work, but all of them need the android device to download the APP and I think that won't work for the glasses. Is there any way I can do it via USB or Wi-Fi without downloading anything on the device?

Answer (score 0):

this is a basic command to get a video from shell

```
 adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/yourfilename.mp4
```

adb is in your sdk platform tools directory.